# Unable to clean event listener in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, removeeventlistener

Problem with removing addEventListener using useEffect return
I also tried to add empty array as a second argument to an useEffect, listener still remains

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import headerLogo from "./icons/logo.svg";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Home({ header }) {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const mouseClickListener = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("LISTENING");
      history.push("/dashboard");
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", mouseClickListener);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickListener);
  });

  return (
    <div className={`${header ? "header-logo" : "home-logo"}`}>
      <img src={headerLogo} alt="logo" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

That was all about, routing. Home component was rendering in another routes also and useEffect was setting event listener each time.
what I did was adding condition by wrapping listener functionality inside useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!header) {

    const mouseClickListener = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("LISTENING");
      history.push("/dashboard");
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", mouseClickListener);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickListener);
}
  });
```